# How to set theme for GNOME (GTK) apps opening as root

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, gtk, 19.10

I use Kubuntu 19.10 and when I open GNOME apps like Nautilus or Gedit as root, they do not show in theme (Qogir-dark) that  I choose for GNOME apps, but in some strange black and white theme.

I tried to put Qogir folder to `/.themes`, but nothing (currently it is in `/usr/share/themes`). How can I correct that?

Comment: *How* are you launching those applications as root?

Comment: `sudo <app name>`

Comment: That's a [bad idea](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006/480481). At least use the `-H` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the Qogir theme in `/usr/share/themes/`. Then use the following command to run an application

```
sudo -H GTK_THEME=Qogir <app name>
```

In general if the theme supports variants (light/dark), you can use the following

```
sudo -H GTK_THEME=<Theme-Name>:<Theme-variant> <app name>
```

Comment: Can I create alias for first part,or I need to create alias for entire command?

Comment: Haven't checked it, but it should be fine to create just for the first part.