# How to change the theme for root user?

Tags: themes, root, gnome-tweaks

Okay, I know that the themes for normal user (with normal privileges) are stored in `home/user/.themes`...

But, I have also noticed that opening an application as root makes the app use a different (default) theme...

So, next I opened Gnome Tweaks as root, and tried to see what theme is being used, and found that the theme list is not the same as the one shown on Gnome Tweaks as a normal user, basically the externally added themes stored in `.themes` folder are missing.

So, I was thinking of making a separate theme for root access, but I couldn't find where to put my themes so that they get included in the root theme list. PRATAP helped me find them under `user\share\themes`...So, I added my theme there, and on running Gnome Tweaks as root the newly added theme was included in the list.

But, applying the new theme didn't change anything.
So, is there a way to change the root user theme?

---

UPDATE-2
I have checked this: [How to set theme for GNOME (GTK) apps opening as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205675/how-to-set-theme-for-gnome-gtk-apps-opening-as-root)
But, this means that I'll have to use some extra attributes with `sudo`, I am wondering if there is a way to make this change permanent (as long as I don't change it again), so that all root apps use the theme by default.

---

My OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Use a bash alias if your problem is with the long command. [GUI apps are not supposed to be run with `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) anyway.